# apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I keep getting this warning when I (re)start Apache.

> `* Restarting web server apache2`
>   `apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName`
>
> `... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName`
>                                                                           `[ OK ]`

This is the content of my `etc/hosts` file:

```
#127.0.0.1  hpdtp-ubuntu910
#testproject.localhost  localhost.localdomain   localhost
#127.0.1.1  hpdtp-ubuntu910

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   testproject.localhost
127.0.1.1   hpdtp-ubuntu910



# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

This is the content of my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName testproject.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/home/morpheous/work/websites/testproject/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/morpheous/work/websites/testproject/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.2/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.2/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to `http://testproject.localhost`, I get a blank page.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 53):

By default Ubuntu doesn't specify a ServerName in the Apache configuration, because it doesn't know what the name of your server is.  It tries a reverse lookup on your IP address, which returns nothing, so it just has to use the IP address as the [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername).

To fix it, either add a ServerName directive *outside of any virtual host* - e.g. in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, or set up a reverse DNS response for your primary IP address - in this case, 127.0.1.1

It's perfectly fine to ignore it also.

Comment: This is counter-intuitive. If I add the ServerName *outside* of any virtual hosts - how can I serve multiple virtual hosts from the same Apache server? (this afterall, is the point of named virtual servers) - UNLESS, you are saying that I can have more than 1 ServerName entry in (say) /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Comment: You can then add ServerName/ServerAlias inside VirtualHost blocks to make that VirtualHost only match the host names you want.  Read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername for the low-down.

Comment: I've been searching for this answer for over an hour. So much crap on the internet concerning this, but this fixed my problem. Thx

Comment: @Mike you and others are genius! I've searching for this answer for *four* days. (Ok, not fully working days.). +1 because this is the first answer that explains that I can add a ServerName directive outside virtual hosts without affecting them. With that in mind, ReinoutS' solution worked for me (+1 to him, too).

Answer (score 28):

Here's a quick fix:

```
echo ServerName $HOSTNAME > /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn
```

Comment: Thanks. None of the fixes using /etc/hosts nor httpd.conf worked for me, but this did.

Comment: Fixed it on Ubuntu 13.04 running apache2, thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Another way around that warning is to put a fully qualified domain name on the `127.0.1.1` line of `/etc/hosts`.  It doesn't even have to be a fqdn that would actually resolve to anything on a dns server.

```
127.0.1.1  hpdtp-ubuntu910.lan  hpdtp-ubuntu910
```

would do the trick, while also preserving the behavior of any programs that aren't expecting the extra `.lan`. The order is important; names with more levels should be specified first, as in this example where the `.lan` address comes before the other address.

Answer (score 7):

**This solution works for my development needs:**

**Background:**

Debian Linux Sid: 
VirtualHost Development: I have 10 server names (10 virtualhost entries inside sites-available)

I assigned each one a unique localhost IP address inside `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   joe   localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1   joe
127.0.1.2   joomla
127.0.1.3   schmoo
127.0.1.4   forrest
127.0.1.5   store
127.0.1.6   publisher
127.0.1.7   studios
127.0.1.8   drupal
127.0.1.9   graphics
127.0.1.10  wordpress
...

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

If you're going to add another virtualhost (I have quite a few for development) add an entry to another localhost IP address, and enable the site before restarting Apache 2.2:

```
127.0.0.11 *newhost*
```

For every entry you want to enable as a VirtualHost file:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/**

**joe  joomla  schoo  forrest  store publisher  studios  drupal  graphics  wordpress**

All virtualhosts are enabled/disabled via a2ensite/a2dissite *hostname*

To suppress the error

> Restarting web server: apache2apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
>   ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain
>   name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName''

edit **httpd.conf** in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` [empty file in Debian]:

```
ServerName 127.0.1.1
```

Look up is then resolved for all names you *add*, *comment out* or *disable* down the line.

In case you forget: The sole VirtualHost *:80 entry only needs to be within the **ports.conf** file,

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
**NameVirtualHost *:80**
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
   # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
   # to <VirtualHost *:443>
   # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
   # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
   Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
   Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Within your VirtualHost entry leave out **VirtualHost *:80**

Example: virtualhost joe

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    **ServerAlias joe**
    **...**
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 6):

Setting `ServerName` in httpd.conf did not work for me. I fixed it by setting `ServerName 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/name`.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 Alpha3 and have `ServerName` defined in both spots.

Source: http://linuxconfig.net/manual-howto/error-solution-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name.html

Comment: Cool, this worked for me also, had the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a server configuration-level ServerName entry. You need to have a ServerName entry outside of any host, for Apache to use as its default.

Putting a ServerName entry inside a VirtualHost will not fix the problem. See *[ServerName Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername)*.

Answer (score 3):

To fix it, we need to edit the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf or /etc/apache2.conf and add the following line:

```
ServerName nameofserver
```

Comment: You're right!  But this answer duplicates the content of crb's answer without providing any new information or insight.  I'd consider deleting it or adding more detail that is different from other people's answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add `ServerName` for the default virtual host. Since it's not there, it is taking the default IP address. And it's a kind of warning. Your web server will still be functional I guess.

Comment: I dont understand your comment. I already have ServerName in my file:

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  ServerName mysite.localhost

Could you please clarify you comment?

Comment: For the -default- virtualhost, not just a specific virtualhost.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to add ServerName in your **httpd.conf** file using following steps

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
   ```

   By default `httpd.conf` file will be blank. Now, simply add the following line to the file.

   ```
   ServerName localhost
   ```

   Save the file and exit from `gedit`. Finally restart the server.

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

2) Add `Include httpd.conf` at the end of `apache2.conf`

Answer (score -1):

If an httpd.conf file doesn't already exist in your etc/apache2 directory after install, then the main apache configuration file, apache2.conf, will not have a reference to it so adding anything to a created httpd.conf will not do anything.  You can simply add the line "ServerName hostname" to the apache2.conf file instead.

Answer (score -1):

Is /etc/hosts still have these entries. (I skipped some answers above)

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   testproject.localhost

Both IP address 127.0.0.1 is same here.

Give different IP address to testproject.localhost from loopback ip subnet.