# Error with Apache2 on Debian Lenny: "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName"

Tags: linux, debian, apache-2.2, debian-lenny

I installed apache2 in Debian Lenny but when I give the command `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` it gives me a statement saying "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName".

How can I change the server name? And how can I make it accessible from another system?

Answer (score 3):

As noted on a [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/103426/), you can either specify a ServerName *outside* of any VirtualHost directive, or place a fully qualified domain name as the *first* name on the 127.0.1.1 line of your /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

put a ServerName in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default

```
ServerName   mydomain.com
```

within the <VirtualHost></VirtualHost> section.

Then, make sure that name resolves to something, either modifying /etc/hosts or using something like dyndns.org to have a hostname that points to your home machine.

The basic installation Listens to all interfaces on port 80, so, once a machine knows to point to your site, it should be able to reach it.

The ServerName warning won't prevent things from working, it just makes things that rely on canonical redirection break.